# MATLAB - matrix function with an independent variable?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying create a function that returns a matrix containing a variable "l" which is an independent variable to be swept for a plot later on.

I would calculate "phi" based on user inputs which include "n" and "d", then I would use "n", "d", and "phi" to find "a", "b", "c", and "d" to create a matrix "m" with. This matrix "m" will be a function of "l".

```
phi = 2*pi*n*d/l;
a = cos(phi);
b = 1i*sin(phi)/n;
c = 1i*n*sin(phi);
d = cos(phi);
m = [a b;c d];
```

I'm really not enjoying MATLAB's coding style as compared to C++ and Python... How would you guys implement this functionality?

Summary: I want a function that returns a matrix which contains an independent variable to be swept for a plot later.

Answer (score 3):

You can two options.

1) Create a function which returns the matrix based on `n`,`d`,`l`

```
BuildM = @(n,d,l)[cos((2*pi*d*n)/l),(sin((2*pi*d*n)/l)*i)/n;n*sin((2*pi*d*n)/l)*i,cos((2*pi*d*n)/l)];

BuildM(4,2,100)  %ans=[0.8763,0.1204i;1.9270i,0.8763]
```

2) Use the symbolic toolbox (if possible)

```
syms n,d,l
phi = 2*pi*n*d/l;
a = cos(phi);
b = 1i*sin(phi)/n;
c = 1i*n*sin(phi);
d = cos(phi);
m = [a b;c d];

subs(m,{'n','d','l'},{4,2,100})  %ans=[0.8763,0.1204i;1.9270i,0.8763]
```

Comment: Does the solution for 1) allow l to be a symbol?

Comment: I'm going to be multiplying a ton of those "m" matrices by eachother, each one will contain the variable "l". Then, later on, I'm going to plot the result and "l" is going to be varied.

Comment: yes, you can combine function handles (the `@` syntax) with symbolic variables.

Comment: Okay, great. I'll test this out when I get home. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to use the [symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/sym.html)?

If so, I guess you want:

```
phi = 2*pi*n*d/sym('l');
a = cos(phi);
b = 1i*sin(phi)/n;
c = 1i*n*sin(phi);
d = cos(phi);
m = [a b;c d];
```

And as a little aside, are you aware of your aliasing of `d`? Is that intentional?

Comment: What do you mean by "aliasing of d"?

Comment: you use `d` in your definition of `d`, but reassign `d` for constructing your matrix `m`. It would be better to not use the same variable name for semantically different values within the same scope.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't notice that.